# Results in CSV should be in lists rather than strings

Tags: python, csv

In my script I calculate certain features per text file. I then write the results to a CSV file. However, I don't seem to be able to get them into lists, I end up with strings. I left out the feature calculations and am just posting the code I use to write to the CSV file. I am a beginner :)

```
fnew = open('results.csv', 'w+')
fnew.write('fileid,feature,resultaat\n')
```

...... Calculate features.

```
    fnew.write(cat+','+sentstr+',perplexity    (bigram),'+str(lmbi.perplexity(sent))+'\n')
    fnew.write(cat+','+sentstr+',perplexity (trigram),'+str(lmtr.perplexity(sent))+'\n')
    fnew.write(cat+','+sentstr+',word_senses,'+str(aver_senses)+'\n')
    fnew.write(cat+','+sentstr+',polarity,'+str(polarity(sent))+'\n')
    fnew.write(cat+','+sentstr+',modality,'+str(modality(Sentence(parse(joined, chunks=False, lemmata=True))))+'\n')
    fnew.write(cat+','+sentstr+',subjectivity,'+str(subjectivity(sent))+'\n')

fnew.close()
```

Comment: Files can only contain text, not lists. What is the exact output problem? You really want to use the `csv` module instead, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I find it difficult to explain, but I think I'll try the CSV module! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store python data structures in a file you might consider [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle

data1 = {'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
         'b': ('string', u'Unicode string'),
         'c': None}

selfref_list = [1, 2, 3]
selfref_list.append(selfref_list)

output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')

# Pickle dictionary using protocol 0.
pickle.dump(data1, output)

# Pickle the list using the highest protocol available.
pickle.dump(selfref_list, output, -1)

output.close()
```

or [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html)

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename) # open -- file may get suffix added by low-level
                          # library

d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
del d[key]      # delete data stored at key (raises KeyError
                # if no such key)
flag = d.has_key(key)   # true if the key exists
klist = d.keys() # a list of all existing keys (slow!)

# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = range(4)  # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(5)   # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL range(4)!

# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it

# or, d=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True) would let you just code
# d['xx'].append(5) and have it work as expected, BUT it would also
# consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower.

d.close()       # close it
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but I'll give it a whirl.

I would recommend using the csv functionality found in [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html).  If you haven't heard of it, matplotlib is an excellent open source graphical library.  Check it out at [www.matplotlib.org](http://www.matplotlib.org).

```
from matplotlib import mlab
writer = mlab.csv.writer(open('results.csv', 'w'))    # pass an open file object and returns a csv writer

# Write the header
writer.writerow(['fileid', 'feature', 'resultant']) 

# Write the data in the same fashion
# ...
```

Re-opening the csv file using csv.reader() in mlab will import all data in lists rather than strings.  Note: this works with any file in csv format, not just those created using csv.writer().

Comment: Not sure if there is a difference, but that example works exactly like that with the standard CSV module.

Comment: I assume this is just the standard `csv` module.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  It is the same module.  Just packaged differently.